# Flutter menu navigator looping

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a set of menu list to be ontap then navigator to the respective page, however I found my solution is not efficient because the menu list keep will adding new more menu from time to time. I try to build a for loop inside the switch case.

```
class MenuData {
  MenuData(this.icon, this.title, this.route);
  final IconData icon;
  final String title;
  final String route;
}

List<MenuData> menuList = [
 MenuData(Icons.move_to_inbox_outlined, 'Menu A',AppConstant.MenuRouteA),
 MenuData(Icons.move_to_inbox_outlined, 'Menu B',AppConstant.MenuRouteB),
 MenuData(Icons.move_to_inbox_outlined, 'Menu C',AppConstant.MenuRouteC),
 MenuData(Icons.move_to_inbox_outlined, 'Menu D',AppConstant.MenuRouteD),
    ];

void _menuNavigate(int index) {
 switch (index) {
        case 1:
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppConstant.MenuRouteA);
          break;
        case 2:
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppConstant.MenuRouteB);
          break;
        case 3:
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppConstant.MenuRouteC);
          break;
        case 4:
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppConstant.MenuRouteD);
          break;
}

Widget MenuCard(){
        Card(
            elevation: 0.2,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _menuNavigate(menu[index]);
                  },
        )
}
```

how to make the _menuNavigate become switch for loop to avoid rewrite many code, i try to build a switch case but this not work and hit error of 'Case expressions must be constant.dart(non_constant_case_expression)'

```
void _menuNavigate(int index){
  switch (index) {
    for(int i=0, i<menuList.length,i++){
          case index:
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, menuList[index].);
          break;
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Switch case don't use like that. So do For loop. You can use for loop in your case, remove your switch. But the switch case will have better than for loop.

Comment: In your switch case you have to case 4 times and you can use loop instead switch case but in loop you will have 4 conditional statement so in your case there will be no code reduced with loop though. so stay with switch case. happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `Navigator.pushNamed(context, menuList[index].route);` as

```
void _menuNavigate(int index) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, menuList[index].route);
}
```